# Why tweepy cannot retrieve media data of some tweets?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm using `tweepy` to develop the program that retrieves media urls and download them. While testing some tweets, I found something weird. So this is what I did:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

status = api.get_status(908827394856947712)
```

The original url of this tweet is 'https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/908827394856947712' and this tweet DOES contain an image. While studying `status._json`, I figured out that the links of media files are contained in either `status._json['entities']` or `status._json['extended_entities']` but I couldn't find `['extended_entities']` and `['entities']` doesn't contain image link.

What makes me annoying is that **some tweets** have this problem and most do not. So why does this happen and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look through the response, you will see `"truncated": true,`

Twitter recently changed how tweets are presented - see their documentation https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets

With your request, you need to set `tweet_mode=extended`

So: `api.get_status('908827394856947712', tweet_mode='extended')`

Comment: Oh, I forgot. sorry for that